# Is there a way to get a list of all panel menu items in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

To get the menu items circled in red on the top-right corner.

[image: img]

I've went thru all the docs for VSCode extension API and counldn't find a solution

Comment: what do you want to do with it, the internal API is much bigger we as extension developers have no access to it

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for replying, the situation is that in our extension, we have a menu item in the top-right corner and there's webview in the panel section contains a 'chat bubble' pointing to that menu item. The 'chat bubble' is currently implemented by a fixed-offset from right, so we want to make sure there's no other menu items in between.